# Vertical Align Images in ScrollView swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to align my images vertical in my scrollView. Unfortunately I can't figure out what the problem is. I think it's something mathematical and this is not my strongest thing. :(

I hope someone can help me out with this problem. I will also provide my code and image of the problem below:

```
//
//  muscleListVC.swift
//  ActiveRest
//
//  Created by Fhict on 04/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Kevin Vugts. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class muscleListVC: UIViewController {

    var images = [UIImageView]()

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        print("Count: \(images.count)")

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        let scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height

        for x in 0...4 {

            let image = UIImage(named: "muscle\(x).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            images.append(imageView)

            var newX: CGFloat = 0.0
            newX = scrollHeight / 4 + scrollHeight * CGFloat(x) / 4
            print("the size is \(newX)")
            contentHeight += newX

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newX, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 166)

            print("the content height: \(contentHeight)")
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: contentHeight)

        }
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

[image]

Thank you very much! <3

Comment: Not getting your problem, what is wrong in the image provided?

Comment: @BharatModi the images needs to be on top 0 position. Currently they are postioned a bit below the top of the frame.

Comment: What constraints you have set to the imageView, also what is your actual requirement, if the image count is dynamic and you need them scroll vertically then why don't you use tableView?

Comment: And i suggest do not set height/content size of scroll manually, let the auto layout calculate it itself based on the content inside it.

Comment: @BharatModi the constraints are set to all edges of the screen. So it will fit on all size of mobile. The image count is dynamic yes. I would like to use scroll view for this purpose if possible. :D

Comment: What do you intend on doing with this: `scrollHeight / 4 + scrollHeight * CGFloat(x) / 4`?

Comment: @ozgur truly i was just fooling around with the settings to get it right. I tried a lot and now my code looks weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you intend to do but I tried to modify your code a bit to make it work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let numberOfImages = 5
        let imageViewHeight:CGFloat = 166.0
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: imageViewHeight*(CGFloat)(numberOfImages))

        var newY:CGFloat = 0

        for x in 0...(numberOfImages-1) {

            let image = UIImage(named: "muscle\(x).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            images.append(imageView)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newY, width: view.frame.size.width, height: imageViewHeight)
            newY = newY + CGFloat(imageViewHeight)
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi sir, this is almost what I am looking for, except one thing. Image 4 is not showing up. and it is still not in the proper position. (y: 0)

Comment: Also the scroll is gone

Comment: Do you have five images?

Comment: I solved it: I have 5 images i added this line of code:

Comment: Sounds good. I also recommend you to read this [tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) which is very well explained about UIScrollView with Autolayout.